# How to hover ion-card inside ion-list

Tags: css, ionic4

I have an ion-list which have a button and card inside it, now I want to change the color of the button and card on hover but can't find a way to do it.
Here is my code. Thanks in advance

Html

```
<div [hidden] = hidden  >
  <ion-list>

<ion-card > 

     <button  inset = true *ngFor="let item of items"  (click)="open($event, item.name)" >
        <ion-card>
         <h2> <b>{{ item.name }} </b>  </h2>

          <p> Recommended for</p>
          {{item.Description}}
        </ion-card>
      <br>
      <br>
    </button>

</ion-card>


</ion-list>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ion-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-color:white; 
    box-shadow: none;
  }


button.item:hover a{
    background-color: slategray;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all u can't hover on device  but u can attach click events for that u need to use ngStyle  in ur components to change color or show if its clicked.

```
<div [hidden] = hidden  >
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">

<ion-card > 
<ion-button (click)="open($event, item.name)" fill="clear" >
                        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" [name]="buttonIcon" [ngStyle]="{'color':color1}"></ion-icon>
                        </ion-button>
        <ion-card>
         <h2> <b>{{ item.name }} </b>  </h2>

          <p> Recommended for</p>
          {{item.Description}}
        </ion-card>
      <br>
      <br>
    </button>

</ion-card>


</ion-list>
</div>
```

> inside ur TS

```
buttonIcon: string = "md-add";
color1: string = "black";

open(event,item){
this.buttonIcon = "done-all"; // icon change name if u want to change icon too
this.color1 ="red"; // any color u want it to change to
//rest of your code
}
```

U can use the same ngstyle on ur ion card as well to change color.
U can also use ion-ripple-effect to show some sort of click feedback on cards.